# IsDate is returning unexpected results

Tags: vb.net

When I am doing in immediate window

```
? IsDate("09/01/14")
   True

? IsDate("10/23/14")
 False
```

I am not sure why IsDate("10/23/14") is returning false.

any suggestions?

This is my entire function. When I pass 09/01/14 then it doesn't return any error, but when I pass 10/23/14 then it returns error.

```
 Public Shared Sub CheckForDate(ByVal ChkText As String, ByRef ErrorCount As Integer)

        Try
            ChkText = ChkText.Replace(" ", "").Trim()
            Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(ChkText, "MM/dd/yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

            If Not IsDate(dt) Then
                ErrorCount += 1

            End If

        Catch
            If Len(ChkText) > 0 Then
                If Not IsDate(ChkText) Then
                    ErrorCount += 1
                End If
            End If

        End Try

    End Sub
```

I tried this

```
 ? DateTime.TryParse("09/01/14", dt)
  True
 ? DateTime.TryParse("10/23/14", dt)
  False
```

Comment: what culture are you in/using? (what is the normal date format for where you are)

Comment: posted the function above

Comment: ....but doesnt answer my question.  `IsDate("10/23/14")` returns true for me but my culture date format is M/D/Y.  From MSDN: Isdate `Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an expression represents a valid Date value.` if your culture is not M/D/Y then it will correctly report false.  "09/01/14" is apparently testing Jan 9, not Sept 1.  Use `DateTime.TryParse` instead and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible that dates in isDate are being processed as dd/mm/yy instead of mm/dd/yy.
Try this code in your application, or be sure your system is processing dates as mm/dd/yy:

```
Imports System.Globalization
Dim ciNewFormat As New CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString())

ciNewFormat.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yy"
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ciNewFormat
```

Comment: I tried tryParse too, but still getting false for 10/23/14

Comment: try using TryParseExact() as Joel said. I'd also use the code I put up there so you can force the date format regardless of the system executing this code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TryParseExact()`. This will force you include information indicating the expected format.

As somewhat indicated in comments on this question, the likely problem is that the machine where you are running assumes a DD/MM/YY format instead of your expected MM/DD/YY format.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify a culture that corresponds to date format used:

```
Public Shared Function IsUSDate(input As String) As Boolean
    Dim culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
    Dim d As DateTime
    Return DateTime.TryParse(input, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, d)
End Function
```